# Show that if $n$ is even then $\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\phi(d)=0$ using only Dirichlet Convolution propertys (without multiplicative function concepts)

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Show that $\displaystyle\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\phi(d)=0$ using only Dirichlet Convolution propertys (without multiplicative function concepts).

I suspect you have to use that  $1\ast \mu=I$ and $f\ast 1=id$ where $1(n)=1$, $id(n)=n$ for all $n$ and $I$ is the unity in the set of arithmetic function.
but not how to use this.

Note: $\phi$ and $\mu$ are Euler and Mobiüs function respectly.

Comment: Hint: It is not actually identically zero.

Comment: You might have some trouble proving it since it is not true as written.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Andrews.

Comment: @Dylan thanks for the correction.